# Необходимо обработать *.json в .txt

Tags: python, json

Необходимо с помощью Python написать программу, которая бы считывала файл в формате json, обрабатывала информацию и записывала ее в файл текст.

В json файле информация дана в следующем формате:

```js
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "some text one",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "some text two",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "some text three",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 22,
    "title": "distinctio vitae autem nihil ut molestias quo",
    "completed": true
  }
```

Необходимо, чтобы в файл в формате текст записывалась информация в следующем формате:

```
Юзер №1
Завершил задачи:
some text three
Осталось выполнить:
some text one
some text two
```

Мой код:

```
import json
import datetime


def My_mission_true(id, title):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    filename = str(id) + '_' + str(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M")) + '.txt'
    with open(filename.rstrip(), 'a') as l:
        l.writelines(f'Юзер №{id}\n')
        l.writelines(f'Осталось выполнить:\n{title}\n')

def My_mission_false(id, title):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    filename = str(id) + '_' + str(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M")) + '.txt'
    with open(filename.rstrip(), 'a') as l:
        l.writelines(f'Юзер№{id}\n')
        l.writelines(f'Завершил задачи:\n{title}\n')

with open('todos.json', 'r') as inf:
    text = json.load(inf)
    for line in text:
        x = line.get('completed')
        if x is True:
            My_mission_true(line['userId'], line["title"])
        elif x is False:
            My_mission_false(line['userId'], line["title"])
```

Проблема в том, что каждая новая задача записывается в новую строку, а надо, чтобы одному юзеру записывались сразу все завершенные задачи и ниже оставшиеся задачи.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import datetime


def get_output(users):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    users_iter = iter(users)
    for user in users_iter:
        filename = str(user) + '_' + str(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M")) + '.txt'
        with open(filename.rstrip(), 'w') as l:
            l.writelines(f'Юзер №{user}\n')
            l.writelines('Осталось выполнить:\n')
            l.writelines('\n'.join(users[user]['not_completed']))
            l.writelines('\nЗавершил задачи:\n')
            l.writelines('\n'.join(users[user]['completed']))


with open('todos.json', 'r') as inf:
    text = json.load(inf)

users = {}
for line in text:
    user_id = line['userId']
    if user_id not in users:
        users[user_id] = {
                'completed': [],
                'not_completed': []
            }
    if line.get('completed'):
        users[user_id]['completed'].append(line['title'])
    else:
        users[user_id]['not_completed'].append(line['title'])
get_output(users)
```